# How to figure out which version of com.android.support.test dependencies I need?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-espresso

I need to write some automated tests in the project I'm working on. So I just copied the required dependencies from some Google's example:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

// Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
```

The problem I ran into was something you could find in a million questions on SO:

```
Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7'. Resolved versions for app (25.3.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

Here I am not asking about the required versions of the test runner, test rules, and the other test dependencies, to be able to sync Gradle and move on.

My question. Is there any quick way to see which versions of `com.android.support.test:runner`, `com.android.support.test:rules`, etc. depend on Support Library 25.3.0?

Of course, I could keep replacing `0.5` with `0.6`, `0.7`, etc, until Gradle syncs successfully, but it's boring and would take me long.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that currently there isn't a version that depends on Support Library 25.3.0 since that version of the support library was released long after the official stable testing artifacts.

If you want to be able to discern this with future versions, you would need to look at the transitive dependencies of each of the artifacts.  You can see these in the maven pom files, or via gradle by running:

`gradle :your_module_name:dependencies`

This being said, you can usually use any version of the support library by telling gradle to ignore Espresso's transitive dependencies like this:

```
androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

you can use the gradle dependencies command above in order to figure out which espresso artifacts are pulling in the transitive dependencies that are causing conflicts.